# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания при прямой речи?

Tags: пунктуация

Месса нашего Господа подошла к моменту, когда мы произносим: “Идите, Месса совершилась”, - что он облекает в крик триумфа: “Совершилось!”

Comment: А почему *месса* с большой буквы?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой по той же причине, вероятно, по которой Литургия в религиозных текстах пишется с заглавной: https://i.imgur.com/NtoqnBl.png (см. еп. Марк (Головков) "Церковный протокол").

Answer (score 1):

*Месса нашего Господа подошла к моменту, **когда мы произносим: “Идите, Месса совершилась”,**  что он облекает в крик триумфа: “Совершилось!”*

Если на месте разрыва слов автора находится **запятая** (между однородными членами, в сложном предложении или закрывающая обособленный оборот), а прямая речь является **повествовательной,** то после прямой речи сохраняется запятая.

В приведенном предложении запятая закрывает придаточное предложение, первая прямая речь повествовательная, поэтому тире не требуется.

Примечание. Текст предложения полностью неясен.

Правило Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159