# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания при прямой речи в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда голос прошепчет: “Ты должен покинуть землю”, голос Отца скажет: “Дитя, приди ко Мне”.

Comment: На подобный вопрос вы уже получили ответ. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/455942/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно расставить знаки препинания при прямой речи?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/455942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8)